# Jackson deserialization of String fails

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Our system utilizes Jackson (Java 11) to deserialize objects from external sources.  When we receive the payload it is in String (UTF-8) format.  It fails to deserialize with an exception (MismatchedInputException)

Cannot construct instance of 'object' (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{

Stack Technology:

- Java 11
- Jackson 2.9.8
- Google Cloud (platform)

We ended up using multiple replaceAll statements just to get the payload in a state that would allow the string to be converted to an object in jackson.  The code really smells...

> I'm not sure if this helps but the payload is pulled from Google PubSub Subscription.  So I have a message receiver listens on the subscription.  I was originally using Springs [JacksonPubSubMessageConverter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/pubsub/support/converter/JacksonPubSubMessageConverter.java) but was throwing the exception above.  I rolled my own, adding the replaceAll(..) below and now that seems to have fixed the problem.

```java
public class ABCMessageReceiver implements MessageReceiver {
  private PubsubMessageConverter converter;
  public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
    Person person = converter.fromPubSubMessage(message, Person.class);
    ...
  }
}
```

```java
payload = "{\n  \"general\": {\n    \"aggregatorId\": \"111111111111\",\n    \"communityId\": \"30303030\",\n    \"dateStamp\": \"2019-07-09\",\n    \"comments\": \"Testing E2E1\"\n  },\n  \"prospect\": {\n    \"firstName\": \"Joe\",\n    \"lastName\": \"Smith\",\n    \"nickName\": \"\",\n    \"email\": \"joe.smith@sample.com\",\n    \"gender\": \"MALE\",\n    \"maritalStatus\": \"SINGLE\",\n    \"dateOfBirth\": \"1956-06-15\",\n    \"veteranStatus\": \"NOTAVETERAN\",\n    \"address\": {\n      \"address1\": \"100 Acme Street \",\n      \"address2\": \"Suite 2300\",\n      \"city\": \"Acme City\",\n      \"state\": \"WI\",\n      \"zip\": \"53214\"\n    },\n    \"phones\": [\n      {\n        \"number\": \"4145551212\",\n        \"type\": \"WORK\"\n      }\n    ],\n    \"financial\": {\n      \"budgetAmount\": 2639,\n      \"budgetFrequency\": \"MONTHLY\",\n      \"medicaid\": true,\n      \"medicare\": true,\n      \"ltcPolicy\": false,\n      \"homeowner\": true,\n      \"vaAid\": false\n    },\n    \"prospectNeeds\": {\n      \"desiredCareLevel\": \"AL\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"tour\": {\n    \"date\": \"2019-07-14T17:00:00.000Z\",\n    \"notes\": \"Testing tour notes 1\"\n  }\n}"
```

```java
payload = payload.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"");
payload = payload.replaceAll("\\\\n", "");
payload = payload.substring(1);
payload = payload.substring(0, payload.length()-1);
```

I don't like the overhead string replacements, but it seems to work for now, until I get another string permutation that I need to support.

Comment: Tell the producer to send you correct JSON.

Comment: If you're receiving JSON data that has been encoded into a JSON string, just decode the string using Jackson, then parse the decoded string using Jackson again.

Comment: @Andreas I updated the question above

Comment: Please update your question with the JSON you are attempting to deserialize.

Comment: @cassiomolin I posted the entire payload that is pulled from the subscription queue

Comment: @jtoepfer If you print the value of `payload`, you'll see that it is perfectly valid JSON. Did you perhaps mean to say the actual payload is what you pasted, and that you messed it up by adding `payload = "..."` around it, obscuring the fact that the payload actually contains `\"` escapes?

Comment: Your JSON document is just fine. How is the `Person` class defined? Does it have a default constructor?

Comment: @Andreas i believe we are talking the same here. The actual payload is not coming back (when printed to log) as JSON as expected, but instead is escaped string.  I just pasted the message from the log. When looking at the value while debugging the issue was the way I saw it wasn't actually JSON but a string.

Comment: Then read [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959720/jackson-deserialization-of-string-fails?noredirect=1#comment100457799_56959720) again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank @Andreas and others that supplied comments. It wasn't connecting at first regarding encoding, I had to come back to it the next day. Yes, I would love it if the producer submitted properly formatted JSON. Here is what I did to get it working, not the best solution, but it works.  I extended JacksonPubSubMessageConverter.java and created a new unencoded version.

UnencodedJacksonPubSubMessageConverter.java

```java
...
public <T> T fromPubSubMessage(PubsubMessage message, Class<T> payloadType) {
    try {
        String payload = message.getData().toStringUtf8();
        payload = removeQuotesIfNecessary(unescapePayload(payload));
        return (T) this.objectMapper.readerFor(payloadType).readValue(payload);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new PubSubMessageConversionException("JSON deserialization of an object of type " + payloadType.getName() + " failed.", ex);
    }
}

private String removeQuotesIfNecessary(String payload) {
    if (payload != null && payload.startsWith("\"") && payload.endsWith("\"")) {
        return payload.substring(1).substring(0, payload.length()-2);
    }
    return payload;
}

private String unescapePayload(String payload) {
    if (payload != null)
        return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(payload);
    return payload;
}
```